# How to get xpath element child by child

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

My xml file is like this:

```
<div class = 'single-review'>
    <div class='review-header' data-id = 'aaabbb'></div>
    <div class='review-content'>
        <span class = 'name'>Alex</span>
        I'd like it
    </div>
</div>
<div class = 'single-review'>
    <div class='review-header' data-id = 'bbbccc'></div>
    <div class='review-content'>
        <span class = 'name'>Bob</span>
        I don't like it
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to using lxml to get all the elements of single review and analyze it one by one:

```
single_reviews = all_data.xpath("//div[@class='single-review']")
for single_review in single_reviews:
     id = single_review.xpath("//div[@class='review-header']/@data-id")
```

But it always returns to me all the ids in the file but not one loop one id. How to fix the problem? Thx!

Comment: Simply add a [dot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256199(v=vs.110).aspx) to the beginning of expression as `.//div[@class='review-header']/@data-id`

Comment: Thank you it works!